# Capture global touch event on C# Windows application

Tags: c#, windows, background, touch, touchscreen

I need to develop an application that runs in background on a touchscreen Windows system.

While the system is in idle, another application shows some images like in a diaporama screensaver.

My application has to capture the touch event wherever on the screen and execute some operations, such as stopping the screensaver and running another application.

How can I capture and handle such a no-metter-where global touch event from background ?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a transparent, always-on-top window and capture the touch events from that

Comment: Thanks paul, I'm already implementing this as a side-solution, but the application will soon need to be expanded for handling other events (such as barcode reader or RFID reader I/O events) so it may be a good choice to make it ready for handling global events. May hooks be a good solution?

Comment: depending on whether you have hardware restrictions, you may be able to use barcode/rfid readers that present themselves as keyboard devices, so it's possible to capture their output by simply listening for OnKeyUp events (this may present the issue of not knowing whether the input came from the 'legit' keyboard or one of the readers, though)

Comment: you got the point paul, readers will work in keyboard emulation mode and no issue should be rised since the device is a touchscreen monitor with no legit keyboard plugged-in (it's controlled from remote). I finally had it working using global MOUSE and KEYBOARD hooks: windows seems to map touch events into normal mouse click events!